# method: => :delete not working and :confirm option ignored

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

After returning to an old Rails project I found none of the destroy/delete links worked and clicking cancel on the confirmation popup would still submit the link.

Example of my code is:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', admin_user_path(@user), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: I'm having this same issue in a Rails 3 app that uses jQuery. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem occurs if you are using jQuery, and if not, then look for something like that:

In my case, I was using:

javascript_include_tag :all  %>

And it was not working, but when I put it like:

javascript_include_tag :defaults %>

It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Chris, Hi. I had the same problem. I deleted Firebug and the problem persisted. I read from another user that he needed to restart Firefox, that didn't work either. Some said try Safari, that didn't work either.

In the end it was a novice thing:

I have helpers to insert an icon, like edit_icon, which return a nice image tag for the edit icon, etc.

One of these helper methods was the delete_icon method, where I wrote like this:

def delete_icon(object=nil)
    link_to image_tag('icons/delete.jpg', :width => 20, :border=>0), object, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete
  end

It was a (good) attempt at DRY, but better it would have been had I just had def delete_icon(object), and not object=nil, because it makes it clearer when I call it that I must pass it the object to destroy. Calling the same method with the object to be deleted worked for me.

In short: double check your helper methods if you're trying to DRY.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it seemed to be an issue with an old combination of prototype and rails.js. The answer from this questions led me to that: [:confirm option in Rails being ignored while using Rails 3 and jQuery UJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879545/confirm-option-in-rails-being-ignored-while-using-rails-3-and-jquery-ujs)

So I downloaded the latest rails.js from https://github.com/rails/prototype-ujs/raw/master/src/rails.js and the latest prototype from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js.

Now everything seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to use jQuery to provide the same confirmation for all delete buttons:

```
;(function($){
  $(function(){
    $('input.destroy').click(function(){
      return confirm($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

You just have to be sure to add class="destroy" to each element, e.g.:

```
= button_to 'Delete', polygon, :method => :delete, :class => "destroy", :confirm => "Are you sure?"
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, this happens because you are calling jQuery code before it's been loaded, or before the elements in the page exist.

To combat this use something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('*[data-confirm]').click(function(){
    return confirm($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quick solution - Just replace conform with data-confirm

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', admin_user_path(@user), 'data-confirm' => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

before

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

in your layout, and also delete

```
//= require jquery
```

line in your **application.js**.

This was the case for me. No idea why it didn't work with original rails jquery.js file.