# Rails: Heroku doesn't understand :patch/:put requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a button made like so that updates my `Lead` object fine locally:

```
<%= link_to status.to_s.titlecase, lead_path(@lead, lead: { status: status }), method: :patch, class: 'dropdown-item' %>
```

But remotely (on Heroku) nothing happens. There's nothing useful in the log:

```
2016-11-15T17:23:45.013893+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/leads/2562?lead%5Bstatus%5D=contact_established" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=57e8b4e9-7a61-4b86-85eb-8f68f1fedd43 fwd="IP" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=44ms status=200 bytes=9678
2016-11-15T17:23:44.972753+00:00 app[web.1]: [57e8b4e9-7a61-4b86-85eb-8f68f1fedd43] Started GET "/leads/2562?lead%5Bstatus%5D=contact_established" for IP at 2016-11-15 17:23:44 +0000
2016-11-15T17:23:44.974230+00:00 app[web.1]: [57e8b4e9-7a61-4b86-85eb-8f68f1fedd43] Processing by LeadsController#show as HTML
2016-11-15T17:23:44.974316+00:00 app[web.1]: [57e8b4e9-7a61-4b86-85eb-8f68f1fedd43]   Parameters: {"lead"=>{"status"=>"contact_established"}, "id"=>"2562"}
2016-11-15T17:23:44.988214+00:00 app[web.1]: [57e8b4e9-7a61-4b86-85eb-8f68f1fedd43]   [1m[36mUser Load (11.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2016-11-15T17:23:44.990722+00:00 app[web.1]: [57e8b4e9-7a61-4b86-85eb-8f68f1fedd43]   [1m[36mLead Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "leads".* FROM "leads" WHERE "leads"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 2562], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2016-11-15T17:23:44.992582+00:00 app[web.1]: [57e8b4e9-7a61-4b86-85eb-8f68f1fedd43]   Rendering leads/show.html.erb within layouts/application
2016-11-15T17:23:45.007497+00:00 app[web.1]: [57e8b4e9-7a61-4b86-85eb-8f68f1fedd43]   Rendered leads/show.html.erb within layouts/application (14.7ms)
2016-11-15T17:23:45.009303+00:00 app[web.1]: [57e8b4e9-7a61-4b86-85eb-8f68f1fedd43] Completed 200 OK in 35ms (Views: 17.2ms | ActiveRecord: 12.6ms)
```

No error message comes back in the `flash`, nothing. I've changed the method between `:patch` and `:put`, still nothing.

What am I missing? Why will that `link_to` update the record locally and do nothing on Heroku?

**Update**

Tried a custom route for Heroku's sake:

```
resources :leads do
  member do
    patch 'update', to: 'leads#update', as: :update
  end
end
```

And changed my link to use the new path:

```
<%= link_to status.to_s.titlecase, update_lead_path(@lead, lead: { status: status }), method: :patch, class: 'dropdown-item' %>
```

Works locally, and I get a page not found error on Heroku.

What's the deal?

Comment: Looks like it's processing it as a `get` request and not hitting update at all. Log something in the update action to make sure you're getting in there.

Comment: your id is also outside `lead`. So if you're looking it up by `params[:id]` you'll need to look up the status by `params['lead']['status']` ...which looks a little funny to me. I would either pass everything inside `lead` or everything outside.

Comment: It's just hitting the get request, yeah--I guess Heroku doesn't support the HTTP verb in the link? It's something weird like that it feels like. I could just do custom routes, but I don't really want to.

Comment: Tried with a new route—see updated question.

Comment: Is it still doing a `GET`? Try putting method and class inside of a hash. It's not reading your method as-is. So trying moving `{method: :patch, class: 'whatever'}` into a hash like-so.

Comment: Still `GET`ting with the hash.

Comment: Have you tried changing to `put`? What about `post`? `patch` isn't a default http/1.1 method.

Comment: *Still* nothing. This is crazy.

Comment: have you read through this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355212/method-delete-not-working-and-confirm-option-ignored ...also, have you tried other browser to make sure it's the same everywhere? Do you have turbolinks disabled?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried your fixes and experimented with Javascript, etc. Still nothing. I ended up answering my own question below if you're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So out of sheer annoyance I made a `:get` request that Heroku can understand. Here're the routes, to wit:

```
resources :leads do
  member do
    get 'change', to: 'leads#change', as: :change
  end
end
```

Controller *(note the non-standard params)*:

```
def change
  if @lead.update_attributes(change_lead_params)
    notice = "#{helpers.full_name(@lead)} changed."
    redirect_to lead_path(@lead), notice: notice
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "#{@lead.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}."
    render :show
  end
end

private

def change_lead_params
  params.permit(:status, :loan_product)
end
```

And the `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to status.to_s.titlecase, change_lead_path(@lead, status: status), class: 'dropdown-item' %>
```

Any information on this issue would be appreciated, since there's no reason for Heroku to deny `:put` requests, right?

Comment: I've never run into such a restriction in Heroku, but I'm not sure I've actually tried patch.  In any case, Heroku says: Heroku's routers pass requests straight through to the application, without special handling based on the particular HTTP method;  The document is https://blog.heroku.com/expanded_http_method_support.

Comment: Maybe it's some JS library preventing it outta Rails 5, I've no idea. I got too frustrated and went with what worked.